# Castle Dynamic Proxy of Interface and not Derived Class

Tags: c#, proxy, castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

```
namespace DynamicInterception
{
    public class Calculator
    {
        public virtual int Div(int a, int b)
        {
            try
            {
                return a / b;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public abstract class Interceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            ExecuteBefore(invocation);
            invocation.Proceed();
            ExecuteAfter(invocation);
        }
        protected abstract void ExecuteAfter(IInvocation invocation);
        protected abstract void ExecuteBefore(IInvocation invocation);
    }

    public class CalculatorInterceptor : Interceptor
    {
        protected override void ExecuteBefore(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInvocation invocation)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start: {0}", invocation.Method.Name);
        }

        protected override void ExecuteAfter(Castle.DynamicProxy.IInvocation invocation)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("End: {0}", invocation.Method.Name);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
            Calculator c = generator.CreateClassProxy<Calculator>(new CalculatorInterceptor());
            var r = c.Div(11, 0);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to replace `public virtual int Div(int a,int b)` 
with interface

```
interface ICalculator
{
    int Div(int a, int b);
}
```

How then should look like proxy declaration?

```
ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
Calculator c = generator.CreateClassProxy<Calculator>(new CalculatorInterceptor());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to add an interface to the `Calculator` and to execute those 2 lines
it will work the same:

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Div(int a, int b);
}

public class Calculator : ICalculator
{

    public int Div(int a, int b)
    {
        try
        {
            return a / b;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();
Calculator c = generator.CreateClassProxy<Calculator>(new CalculatorInterceptor());
```

But you didn't really do anything by that - you are still creating the proxy for a concrete derived type. I assume you want something like `"CreateClassProxy<ICalculator>"`. That won't work because the `CreateClassProxy` has a generic constraint on `where TClass : class`.

What you do have is a variety of `CreateInterfaceProxt..` Methods which you can try. But still a naive execution like the following won't work:

```
ICalculator c = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<ICalculator>(new CalculatorInterceptor());
c.Div(1, 2);
```

It will execute, call the interceptor and will fail when running the `invocation.Proceed();` with the error:

> System.NotImplementedException This is a DynamicProxy2 error: The
>   interceptor attempted to 'Proceed' for method 'Int32 Div(Int32,
>   Int32)' which has no target. When calling method without target there
>   is no implementation to 'proceed' to and it is the responsibility of
>   the interceptor to mimic the implementation (set return value, out
>   arguments etc)

So as the good indicative (seriously) errors of Castle specify - you must somehow have an implementation for it - or by indicating it yourself in the interceptor - of by having a `Component` registered for that interface.

Instead you can do like this: *(Check comments in code)*

```
ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();

ICalculator calculator = new Calculator();
var proxyCalculator = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(typeof(ICalculator),calculator, new CalculatorInterceptor());

calculator.Div(1, 2); // Will execute but will not be intercepted
((ICalculator)proxyCalculator).Div(11, 0); //Will execute and will be intercepted
```

But after saying all I said above, if the purpose behind all of this is to have an interceptor intercept your method then just just the "good-old" registering to the container:

```
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(
    Component.For<CalculatorInterceptor>(),
    Component.For<ICalculator>()
             .ImplementedBy<Calculator>()
             .Interceptors<CalculatorInterceptor>());

var calculator = container.Resolve<ICalculator>();
calculator.Div(1, 0);

// Output:
// Start: Div
// Attempted to divide by zero
// End: Div
```